# Sorting not working on date column with the jQuery tablesorter plugin on de production server

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter, date-format

I'm using the [tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) on a generated table using ASP.NET. My problem is that there is a column with some date (Format = YYYY-MM-DD) and the sorter is only working on my local machine.
When published on the server, it doesn't. I turn on the debug mode and found that on the local machine, the type of the column that is auto-detected is `isoDate` and on the production machine, it's `shortDate`.

**Important:** When you look at the date, it is exactly looking the same. For example: 2010-11-15. There is NO difference. But I'm pretty sure the local settings are very different on the machine itself so that must explain why one is considered to be a isoDate and the other one an shortDate.

I also validated that the plugin include a sorter for both of these format. I have the latest version and nobody seems to have that bug.

What am I doing wrong?

What I have already tried, to force the use of the isoParser :

```
$("#ChangeLogTable1").tablesorter({headers: { 0: { sorter: 'isoDate'}}});
```

***EDIT***

I've change my code for this (see below) to force the sort "as a string" and it work because my date format give me this possibility but it would not work if the format would be dd-mm-yyyy. So my question will still stay open but this is a workaround.

```
$(this).tablesorter({ headers: { 0: { sorter: 'text'} }});
```

***EDIT 2***

Here is some of the table html, I just replaced some of sensitive data with XXXX

```
<div style="width: 1300px">

        <table id="ChangeLogTable1" class="table tablesorter table-bordered"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Date de correction</th>
            <th>Correcteur</th>
            <th>BugID</th>
            <th>Catégorie</th>
            <th>Module</th>
            <th>Description de la correction</th>
            <th>Impact</th>
            <th>Rapporté par</th>
            <th>Demandé par</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td width="125px"> 2012-10-10</a></td>
                <td width="100px"> XXXX</td>
                <td width="75px"> XXXX</td>
                <td width="100px"> XXXX </td>
                <td width="100px"> XXXX </td>
                <td width="300px"> XXXX </td>
                <td width="300px"> </td>
                <td width="100px"> XXXX </td>
                <td width="100px"> </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Can you share some of your HTML.

Comment: The HTML is the same on both machine (checked with winmerge) and the column only contains date in this format 2010-11-15 so there is no need for html code. See updated question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked for HTML because the `isoDate` parser will only set itself when the data is in this format `####/##/##`:

```
/^\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}$/.test(s);
```

The `shortDate` parser will only set itself when the data looks like this `##/##/####` or `##/##/##`:

```
/\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4}/.test(s); // from tablesorter v2.0.5
```

So either the parser code has been altered or the html format is being interpreted incorrectly; but this doesn't explain why setting `isoDate` in the `headers` option doesn't work.

It could be possible that the first row date unintentionally has a different format, or some inline HTML (i.e. numbers wrapped in a span for styling), from the other rows making the code which detects which parser to use in each column misinterpret the data. So that's why I asked what the HTML looks like.

I know you shared the initialization code, but I think I should also ask if there are any other configuration options, that aren't shown, being used since modifying the `textExtraction` function could also alter how the data is being processed.

Comment: I just added some new information on my question. Any other idea?

Comment: Did you try removing the extra `</a>` in the cell? Also, defining the width of the cell could be done in the header `th` or in a `col`, then you only have to do it once.

Comment: OMG! I've never saw the </a> and the </a> was present both on the local machine and the server but the server seems to react differently! I remove it and now everything work perfectly! Thanks!